# node.js https no response 'end' event, 'close' instead?

Tags: node.js, https

I am using node.js v. 0.4.8. When I create a HTTPS server, I never get the response.on('end', ...) event (but I do for a HTTP one). I read the issue reports on node's github page - https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/728, and apparently this is an issue that regressed into 0.4.8. response.on('close', ...) seems to have the same functionality, but I do not know enough about HTTP/HTTPS to judge. Can I use it as replacement for response.on('end', ...), and is this likely to cause any problems in future?

You can see a code sample below.
Thanks in advance!

```
var request = "JSON_request";
var https = require('https');
var options = { 
        host:"someHost.com",
        path:"somePath",
        method: "POST", 
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(request)
        }
    };

var req = https.request(options, function(res){
    var response = "";
    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        console.log("INFO: "+chunk);
        response += chunk;
    });

    // This never happens
    res.on('end', function(){
        console.log("End received!");
    });

    // But this does
    res.on('close', function(){
        console.log("Close received!");
    });
});

req.on('error', function(error){
    console.log("Error: "+error);
});

req.write(request);
req.end();
```

Comment: is it the same with http? 'close' is emitted after socket was actually closed, 'end' on the end of 'http' request. There may be a problem with request and http parser does not think it have full request. Can you show full request headers?

Comment: Wow, I just had the same issue here. Was looking at the various http examples around and found when I switched to https, it would stay open forever. But "close" fixed it! Answer accepted :).

Comment: Ah thanks man! God bless you..I've spent hours on this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe this issue has been fixed as of [commit `de09168`](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/de09168), and there hasn't been any action on this question for months BUT here is the answer:

On the comments for [issue 728](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/728) Node.js creator Ryan Dahl [says](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/728#issuecomment-1730080):

> This isn't a bug. Responses are not guaranteed to have an 'end' event. Use 'close'.

Though later he [says](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/728#issuecomment-2316772):

> i take back what i said before. we should probably make this work.

Either way it seems `close` and `end` are pretty much interoperable in this use case.  The relevent code in the `node.js` core `tls.js:681` renforces that interpretation:

```
process.nextTick(function() {
  self.encrypted.emit('end');
  self.cleartext.emit('end');
  self.encrypted.emit('close');
  self.cleartext.emit('close');
});
```

Comment: Neither `end` nor `close` are firing for me in node v0.12.7. request 'end' does fire though. Edit: it's "finish" now as Dario pointed out.

Answer (score 9):

Since node.js 0.8.12 **finish** event is emitted on HTTP responses' end function. I wrote all the details in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14093047/189467).