# Adding a hook to globally log all node HTTP responses in node.js / express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using node.js and express to handle HTTP requests and responses. By using the `http.ServerRequest`  event, I can add a hook in and log HTTP requests. There doesn't seem to be a similiar event for `http.ServerResponse` and I am wondering how to log all the HTTP responses with one piece of code that my server sends?

Comment: There is no way to do this. `"request"` is emitted by `HttpServer` which express extends. The easiest way would be to overwrite `.send` or `.end` with a thin logging proxy.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up monkey-patching the http.ServerResponse methods - it worked great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I created a package that does such a thing, out of a similar need. Check out [express-request-logger](https://github.com/mathrawka/express-request-logger)

The heart of the program is like this, it contains some extra code so you can have your own key-value map of data that gets logged per request:

```
// Save the real end that we will wrap
var rEnd = res.end;

// To track response time
req._rlStartTime = new Date();

// Proxy the real end function
res.end = function(chunk, encoding) {
  // Do the work expected
  res.end = rEnd;
  res.end(chunk, encoding);

  // And do the work we want now (logging!)

  // Save a few more variables that we can only get at the end
  req.kvLog.status = res.statusCode;
  req.kvLog.response_time = (new Date() - req._rlStartTime);

  // Send the log off to winston
  var level = req.kvLog._rlLevel;
  delete req.kvLog._rlLevel;
  logger.log(level, '', req.kvLog);
};
```

The above code runs as middleware in express. Take a look at the code, and if you have further questions, get in touch with me on here or github.

Comment: In current versions of Node.js, `res` should generate a `"finish"` event which you can use instead of proxying the end method.

Comment: I get: TypeError: winston.loggers is not a constructor

Answer (score 10):

It is no longer needed to monkeypatch, as long as there is a **finish** event emitted on [end() function](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/http.js#L894) since node.js 0.8.12.

Actually, it was initially published as **end** in [0.8.8](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/790d651f0dfae13f1e2b799820ab18ac09f251b7) (check also [this](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3855)) but [it broke writable streams' duplexes](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/836a06fc4f4920d5e9675763290c97aa4e7288fe), so it was renamed to finish.

Comment: I've checked in Node 0.8.14 and 0.8.23 and `end` is emitted, not `finish`. The commits you've linked are included in 0.9 / 0.10 branches (it's now being displayed by GH below the commit message since a couple of weeks ago).

Comment: Is is possible to get the response message on the finish event?

Comment: `end` seems to work for me too, whereas `finish` does not. I'm confused!

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to log (requests and/or responses), check out [express-winston](https://github.com/bithavoc/express-winston/blob/master/Readme.md). [Unlike morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/issues/32), it can even log the request/response body.

Example in coffeescript:

```
expressWinston.requestWhitelist.push('body')
expressWinston.responseWhitelist.push('body')
app.use(expressWinston.logger({
      transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({
          json: true,
          colorize: true
        })
      ],
      meta: true, // optional: control whether you want to log the meta data about the request (default to true)
      msg: "HTTP {{req.method}} {{req.url}}", // optional: customize the default logging message. E.g. "{{res.statusCode}} {{req.method}} {{res.responseTime}}ms {{req.url}}"
      expressFormat: true, // Use the default Express/morgan request formatting, with the same colors. Enabling this will override any msg and colorStatus if true. Will only output colors on transports with colorize set to true
      colorStatus: true, // Color the status code, using the Express/morgan color palette (default green, 3XX cyan, 4XX yellow, 5XX red). Will not be recognized if expressFormat is true
      ignoreRoute: function (req, res) { return false; } // optional: allows to skip some log messages based on request and/or response
    }));
```

Comment: This is the modern and perhaps most correct answer for today.

Answer (score -6):

If you're using express' res.send() for all responses, and you don't mind inserting code into the express module, you can insert
into

.../node_modules/express/lib/response.js:

```
43 res.send = function(body, headers, status){
44   console.log("\n...your log text here..." + body);
45   // allow status as second arg
46   if ('number' == typeof headers) {
47     status = headers,
48     headers = null;
49   }
```

I don't think you can listen for a non-error event - "close" doesn't seem to fire upon res.send();.  I guess it's because send() is always called somewhere in your code.

Comment: This is a bad idea. See the other answers, instead.