# Undocumented response.finished in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

Just starting off with node.js and following [Node Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849517185) but I am stuck on URL routing part.

here is the code from the book itself:

```
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var pages = [
    {route: '', output: 'Woohoo!'},
    {route: 'about', output: 'A simple routing with Node example'},
    {route: 'another page', output: function() {return 'Here\'s '+this.route;}},
    ];

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

   var lookup = path.basename(decodeURI(request.url));

    pages.forEach(function(page) {

        if (page.route === lookup) {
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.end(typeof page.output === 'function'? page.output() : page.output);
        }
    });
    if (!response.finished) {  // couldn't find any documentation for response.finished

        response.writeHead(404);
        response.end('Page Not Found!');
    }
}).listen(8080);

console.log('Server started');
```

---

Though code runs without any errors and seems it does what they meant but looking to the [node.js documetation](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.10/api/http.html#http.request) and searching on Google for `response.finished` doesn't yields any result.

and here is the quote from the book in context of explaining `response.finished`

[image: response.finished]

Could you please explain what the actually meant by that quotation or any citation for `response.finished`.

Comment: Looks like it's a flag on writable streams that is set with `.end()`, but I can't find any docs either.

Comment: It's mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14093047/57135

Comment: See my answer. It is documented as of this date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's declared [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L72) and set [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L583). TL;DR: when `response.end()` is (almost) done, the `finished` property is set to `true` (`response` is an instance of `http.OutgoingMessage` or a subclass).

I actually have to disagree with the comment about it not being a race condition, because I think it is. Even though `forEach` isn't asynchronous itself, in this case it calls asynchronous functions (`writeHead()` and `end()`). If those functions take a bit of time, the check for `response.finished` might be called too soon and you'll end up with an error.

Also, I wonder if `finished` should be used at all. It's not documented and not exposed to the outside world through a method. In other words, it might work now but there's no guarantee it will keep working in the future.

Answer (score 3):

As of this date, response.finish is documented (actually per the doc it was introduced in v0.0.2)

From [the Node API Official Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_finished),

> response.finished
>
> Added in: v0.0.2
>
> Boolean value that indicates whether the response has completed. Starts as false. After response.end() executes, the value will be true.

Comment: thanks for looking into the documentation. BTW it took quite a long from Node team to document it:)

Comment: @exexzian Found this post from Google when I was searching for `response.finished`. Even though your question is 4 yo, I thought my answer would be helpful to others who stumble on this post like me :D