# Node.js / Express on response event

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create a middleware that logs response times and status codes and sends it to a database. However, I'm not sure what event to use. In node's documentation there's a `close` event but it is never fired. `end` doesn't work either. However, `header` does, but I can't find any documentation.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.on('close', function() {
    console.log('close')
  })

  res.on('end', function() {
    console.log('end')
  })

  res.on('header', function() {
    console.log('header')
    console.log(res.statusCode)
  })

  next()
})
```

Only `header` fires, and it does return the correct res.statusCode.

My questions:

1. Why isn't `close` firing? Why is `header` firing?
2. Is this a reliable way to go?

Comment: What version of Node? HTTP, or HTTPS? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537510/node-js-https-no-response-end-event-close-instead?rq=1) hints that the scheme makes a difference. It may also simply be a bug/regression in Node. Also: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1611 ...also, it appears [a change w/r/t this is in the works.](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3855)

Comment: http. node v 0.8.8. Weird how neither `end` or `close` work. Do you think I could use `finish` without any issues?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`close` event emited only if connection was terminated before response.end() called.
`header` event fired by [`connect`](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect). This is not node.js http.ServerResponse native event.

Look at `connect` [`responseTime`](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/responseTime.js) middleware. I think it should help you.

**Update**:

Here is `header` event documentation https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/gh-pages/tests.md#patch

`header` fired from writeHead method proxied by `connect` https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/patch.js

Comment: yeah that's where i learned about `header`, but i couldn't find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 35):

There is an [finish event](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_finish), it is emitted when the response has been sent.

```
app.use(function(req, res,next){
    res.on('finish', function(){
        console.log('the response has been sent');
    });
    next();
});
```

Comment: Note: it does not imply that the client has received anything yet.
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_finish

Comment: Does this event have access to the `req` or `res` objects?

Comment: @pir you have access to the req and res from the outer function. If you reference them again in the nested handler function for the `finish` event, they will still be valid.