# How does the event: 'close' work in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm experimenting with the `close event` in Node.js. I'm very new to Node.js so I'm not sure if this is a decent question or a sad one.

Documentation for `close event`: 
http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_close_2

I want to output to the console a message if the browser is closed before the `end event` is reached.

While the server ran and before it got to 15 seconds, I tried closing the browser and killing the process through Chrome Tools. No message is output to the console and if I open up other connections by visiting localhost:8080 with other windows, I quickly get a 'hello' indicating my node server thinks there are at least two connections.

I'm either not understanding how to kill processes in Chrome  or how the event close works.

Or if `End` and `Close` are the same - [node.js https no response 'end' event, 'close' instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537510/node-js-https-no-response-end-event-close-instead) - why isn't my "They got impatient!" message still ouput in the console?

How can you output to a console if the process was ended before the event end was reached?

```
var http = require('http'),
    userRequests = 0;


http.createServer(function(request,response){
userRequests++;

response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'});

if ( userRequests == 1 ){

    response.write('1st \n');
    setTimeout ( function() {
        response.write('2nd Thanks for waiting. \n');
        response.on('close', function() {

            console.log("They got impatient!");

        });
        response.end();
    }, 15000);
    response.write('3rd \n');
}
else {
    // Quick response for all connections after first user
    response.write('Hello');
    response.end();
}
}).listen(8080, function() {
console.log('Server start');
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - move the event handler for the close message outside the timeout function - you're not hooking up the close handler until after your timeout expires, and probably missing the event.

Second, you never decrement userRequests anywhere; shouldn't there be a `userRequests--;` line somewhere? This would be throwing off your logic, since it'll always look like there's more than one request.

Comment: Very good. The first point is right. That solved the problem. The second point is right too - I need to learn how to dequement the user, however, I can't get it working after putting `userRequests--;' inside the `listener` on the `close` event. It seems once `end` is hit, `close` stops listening. Any ideas?